'Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'
I am trying to run a django application with a postgres db on docker-compose. I can run it perfectly but as soon as I do a post request, I get this error:
FAILED tests/test_email.py::TestUser::test_list_to - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='172.17.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/customers/516c7146-afc0-463b-be0e-7df01e8a86f6/emails (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7ff6544eada0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
This is my docker-compose file:
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: verySecretPassword
      POSTGRES_USER: administrator
      POSTGRES_DB: project
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://administrator:verySecretPassword@db:5432/project
    volumes:
      - .:/app

this is my Dockerfile:
# Use the official Python image as a base image
FROM python:3.10

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install Django and Django REST Framework
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir django djangorestframework

# Install system dependencies for psycopg2 (PostgreSQL client)
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql-client

# Copy the requirements file and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the Django project files to the container
COPY . /app/

# Install system dependencies for psycopg2 (if necessary)
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y libpq-dev gcc

# Install psycopg2 (or psycopg2-binary)
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir psycopg2-binary==2.8.6

# Copy the input.json file to the container
COPY input/input.json /app/input/


EXPOSE 8080


# Run Django development server
# CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
CMD ["bash", "-c", "sleep 10 && python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080"]

My settings.py file (DATABASES part only)
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'assignment',
        'USER': 'administrator',
        'PASSWORD': 'verySecretPassword',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

What is trying to call the backend service?  Where is that code running, and what URL is it trying to connect to?  (Your error message shows an IP address 172.17.0.1; where does that come from?)

try this into your compose file. I set environment variables inside .env file.
db:
    image: postgres:latest
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    env_file:
      - ./.env

